# Test for I/O Completion Port Support

Tags: c#, linux, mono, iocp

I found the following code in the code of an SMTP mail server ([LumiSoft Mail Server](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/download/downloads/)). According to the method's name, it test whether the platform supports [I/O Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets if IO completion ports supported by OS.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool IsIoCompletionPortsSupported()
{
    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);
    try{                            
        SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        e.SetBuffer(new byte[0],0,0);
        e.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback,111);
        s.SendToAsync(e)

        return true;
    }

    catch(NotSupportedException nX){
        string dummy = nX.Message;
        return false;
    }
    finally{
        s.Close();
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine but fails on Mono/Linux. The method `SendToAsync`, like its name says, executes asynchronously. It even executes in another thread. However, when it starts to execute, the finally part of this method already closed the socket and causes an `ObjectDisposedException` in the other thread.

So, is an incorrect technique to test for IOCP suppport? Why does it work on Windows? What is the proper way to test for IOCP support?

Comment: I/O Completion Port is different from Async support. IOCP is windows-specific. Linux use `epoll()`, not IOCP.

Comment: Mono emulates IOCP. See https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=644428

Answer (score 2):

The test simply determines if an async operation results in a `NotSupportedException` or not. The test code doesn't care about the async operation completing it simply cares if it throws an exception when called.

The person who wrote the test probably assumes that async operations imply IOCP support and that this test should really be named "IsAsyncOperationSupported()".

I imagine that mono/linux doesn't support async operations everywhere due to the lack of IOCP support and the person who wrote the test knows this...